# wpn-xm.exe fails to start after Windows 10 update

Tags: wpn-xm

My Windows10 machine has just installed its Windows10 April 2018 upgrade.

Now wpn-xm.exe fails to start with message "This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "windows".  I downloaded and ran the latest WPNXM-0.8.6 installer, but it made no difference.

Has anyone else experienced this or can give any clue what to try next?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on my Windows 10 x64. I overwritten the files using this zip file: https://github.com/WPN-XM/server-control-panel/releases/download/v0.8.6/wpnxm-scp-0.8.6-x86_64.zip 
That solved my problem to start wpn-xm.exe

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and looked on the official GitHub bugs page where the bug appears to be still open (And the fix given there didn't work for me).

However, I've managed to get around it by simply not using the WPN-XM control panel and accessing everything directly in the folder on my machine.

You can start PHP/NGINX/ETC by clicking "start.bat" and also start "status.bat" to see what is running. To stop your local server just click "stop.bat". The WPN-XM console and browser interface can also be directly accessed this way until a working fix is released for the control panel.

Comment: Yes, I had subsequently found exactly that out and I too am running at the moment with "start.bat".  Thanks for the reply.